# What is purpose of node name while creating a node in neo4j if we can't see and use them?

Tags: neo4j, nosql, nodes, graph-databases

Suppose I create a node "Tom" with label "lblPlayer":

```
Create (Tom:lblPlayer)
```

then after creating and querying it, it returns an empty node with ID=0 and lblPlayer but Tom is shown nowhere. So what is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 1):

Tom is a reference for the rest of the query.
It allows you to add properties, or create relations.

SET Tom.name = "Tom"

Comment: May I suggest you the book "Learning Neo4j 3.x" (packt publishing). Been told the pedagogy is good. Disclaimer: I wrote it so I'll get a part of your money

Comment: but I can get the same using lblPlayer i.e. lblPlayer.name

Comment: If you dont need to refer to the node in following lines, you can do

CREATE ( :lblPlayer{name:"Thomas"})